# How to get all parent folders of a file path

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with file paths as `varchar`s:

```
select * from file;
+-------------+
| path        |
+-------------+
| a/b/c/d/e/f |
| a/b/c/x/y   |
+-------------+
```

I need to get all the folders that contain one of these files:

```
select * from parent_folders;
+-----------+
| parent    |
+-----------+
| a         |
| a/b       |
| a/b/c     |
| a/b/c/d   |
| a/b/c/d/e |
| a/b/c/x   |
+-----------+
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
DELIMITER ;;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS explode_paths;;
CREATE PROCEDURE explode_paths() BEGIN
  DECLARE folders INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT path FROM file;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS parent_folders;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE parent_folders (
    parent VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ) ENGINE=Memory;

  OPEN cur;
    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cur INTO value;
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;

      SET folders = (SELECT LENGTH(value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(value,'/','')));
      SET i=1;
      WHILE i <= folders DO
        INSERT IGNORE INTO parent_folders VALUES (SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,'/',i));
        SET i = i + 1;
      END WHILE;
    END LOOP;

    SELECT * FROM parent_folders;
  CLOSE cur;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```